# Currency Mask infinite loop

Tags: iphone, currency, mask

I need to create a currency mask. I did lines of command and it's works fine, but when I set the value in textfield, an infinite loop occurred. I monitoring the textfield with Editing Changed behavior, to catch each caracter that the user set, but when I try to change the text value, the infinity loop happens.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the text in the `textFieldDidChange`? Because if you do, the `textFieldDidChange` notification is going to fire again and the text is set again and the notification will fire again and so on...

I tried doing this as well. The only solution I could come up with is formatting your text when the user leaves the `textField`. I did not find a way to reliable format the contents of the `textField` while the user was editing it.

Comment: its very strange... because the contact app there is a mask when the user was editing it. but its ok!!
thank u very much for information :)